# Get_field value to show in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to use do_shortcode to display data from an advanced custom field which is in the admin cms.

I have an advanced customed field called  'meta_slider_shortcode'. I would like the do_shortcode to display the data that is in the meta_slider_shortcode' field.

Here is my php:

```
<?php

$meta = get_field( "meta_slider_shortcode" ); 

echo do_shortcode('$meta');

?>
```

Comment: What is the return of `$meta`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of $meta. If it does not contain square brackets then add it in do_shortcode like do_shortcode("[$meta]");

Answer (score 0):

The short code cant have ' ' wrapped around the variable.

Here is a working example:

```
<?php

$meta = get_field( "meta_slider_shortcode" ); 

echo do_shortcode($meta);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have short code then use it some thing like this

```
$yourvar = do_shortcode( '[your-short-code]' );
echo $yourvar;
```

or

```
echo do_shortcode( '[your-short-code]' );
```

in your case it would

```
echo do_shortcode(get_field( "meta_slider_shortcode" ));
```